# RecyclerView and onTouch() highlight, how to remove it when returning from details activity to list?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, master-detail, android-background, ontouch

### My plan

I'm trying to highlight a selected list element in a RecyclerView of a master detail activity.

- In portrait mode, the details are displayed in a new activity.
- In landscape mode, the details are displayed in a fragment in the same activity as the list.

---

### My code

I have `private int pos = RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;`
  in my RecyclerView Adapter class, the background set to this XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/selected_color" android:state_selected="true"/>
</selector>
```

and my onTouch() and onBindViewHolder() look like this:

```
itemView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    notifyItemChanged(pos);
                    pos= getLayoutPosition();
                    notifyItemChanged(pos);
                    return false;
                }
            });


@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        viewHolder.itemView.setSelected(pos == position);
    }
```

---

### My problem

The selected item stays highlighted on portrait mode when I return from the details activity to the list. How can I fix this or is there a different/better way to achieve my goal?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this looks good for your use case. On the activity `OnResume` you can set the `pos` to `-1` or something which would deselect the item when coming back from details?

Comment: Thx, it works. :)